# Why does okhttp add a newline (\n) to response output?

Tags: java, okhttp

Pseudo code:

```java
import okhttp3.*;
private final OkHttpClient mClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().readTimeout(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(createUrl(path, parameters)).build();
okhttp3.Response response = mClient.newCall(request).execute();
String body = response.body().string();
System.out.print(body);
```

My HTTP server does not send any newlines (\n) in the BODY of the message (and I verified this using curl); when I print out the received response body from okhttp, I always see \n. Any ideas on how to let okhttp know not to add \n?

Comment: "My HTTP server does not send any newlines" - Are you sure about this? The HTTP Standard specifies a newline (CRLF) between the HTTP headers and the HTTP body. HTTP parsers tend to anticipate the newline, as it is part of the standard.

Comment: Try `curl -I <domain> | xxd` and see if you notice `0a` at the end of the HTTP Response Header. It's common to see `0d0a0d0a` or `\r\n\r\n`.

Comment: I should clarify: Beyond the HTTP headers (as you indicate), my server does not send \n. I will update the question to indicate this information. I confirmed using curl again.

Comment: This is most unlikely. Check your observations.

Comment: Thank you all for your time. It's not important enough for me right now to create a test case against a public server. Let's keep this here in case somebody else finds the same problem.

Comment: I am having the same issue!! It is appending a '\n' to my json. something like {...}\n